# Why doesn't matlab find this function call?

Tags: python, matlab, mex

So I downloaded some compiled matlab files. I see the following files in a folder.

```
makemesh.mexmaci64  
makemesh.mexw32  
makemesh.mexw64
```

I added this folder to userpath, and now the path variable shows that this folder exists in it.

I try to run a test script that came with these files, and I get this error message.

```
Undefined function 'makemesh' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
```

Now to trouble shoot, I need to find,

1. Does it find the function, but the data type is wrong.
2. It doesn't even find the function.

And if it is case 1.

1a. How do I find out what is the proper data structure that function expects.

I am good with python, but new to matlab, so any tips you can add regarding how to query the help string of a function, how to print out the function signature given a function name (like ?function_name in ipython interface) would be super useful.

thank you,

Comment: What does `which makemesh` and `computer('arch')` return?

Comment: My guess is you are on linux and you have the files only for windows and mac. That's why help is not finding any function.

Comment: @Daniel computer('arch') returns glnxa64

Comment: @LokeshA.R. This could be the case, anyway to confirm this? Probly thats what the file extensions mean? w64 & maci64?

Comment: Just saw your response, somebody already answered. For running a linux compatible mex file, it needs the extension mexa64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`computer('arch')` returns `glnxa64` which stands for GnuLiNuX 64bit. You have downloaded binaries for Win32bit (mexw32), Win64bit (mexw64) and IOS on Intel (mexmaci64). Either get the source files to compile it yourself or the binaries for linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `which <functionName>` to see if Matlab is seeing your function.

Have you tried `help <functionName>` to see if there are any useful comments on what your function is expecting?

Comment: which makemesh returns this: 'makemesh' not found.

Comment: also help makemesh returns this: No help found for makemesh

Answer (score 1):

You can find the location of a file on your path by using the which command. For example:

```
which makemesh.mexw64
```

should print the location of that file to the terminal. If you get

> 'makemesh.mexmaci64' not found.

then it means that the file does not exist on your path.

As for finding out what the function wants, I'd start with "help"

```
help makemesh.mexw64
```

and see if that gives you anything useful.

I suspect that somehow or other, your matlab is not recognizing the mex file as a function, so I'd start looking there.

Comment: help and which are used without any file extension.

Comment: @Daniel they dont have to be.

Comment: For `which` you are right, never noticed it could be used with files, but a mex never contains a help. `help makemesh.mexw64` can not find anything.

Comment: which along with the filename with extension prints location of the file, which without the extension prints 'makemesh' not found.

Comment: @jason then the issue your having is that matlab isn't recognizing the mex file as a function, even though it is finding the file on the path. my guess is that there's some problem with the file itself.